# How to do generic onTouchEvent method for kotlin?

Tags: android, generics, methods, kotlin

I have such a method. In loginactivity.kt. What I want to do is make this method generic and use it everywhere. I want to write a method in CommonExtensions.kt, but I can't write it right and I get an error. How can I make Generic become

LoginActivity.kt

```
override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {

    val imm = this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(this.currentFocus?.windowToken, 0)

    return super.onTouchEvent(event)
}
```

CommonExtensions.kt

```
fun Context.onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {

val imm = this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(this.onTouchEvent()?.windowToken, 0)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of options:

- Create a basic class for Activities, for example `BaseActivity` and override `onTouchEvent` method there. Inherit from that activity other activities.
- Create some util file, for example `UiUtils.kt` and define method of hiding keyboard there, e.g.:

  ```
  fun hideKeyboard(view: View) {
      val imm = view.context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
      imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
  }
  ```

  Call it from your activities' `onTouchEvent()` method:

  ```
  override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {        
      hideKeyboard(someView)
      return super.onTouchEvent(event)
  }
  ```
- Create extension function on `View` in your `CommonExtensions.kt` file:

  ```
  fun View.hideKeyboard() {
      val imm = context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
      imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(windowToken, 0)
  }
  ```

  And call it from `onTouchEvent()` method:

  ```
  override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {        
      someView.hideKeyboard()
      return super.onTouchEvent(event)
  }
  ```

Comment: what should I write instead of someview?

Comment: it is reference to any view, for example EditText.